# Can Solr tolerate loss of all cores on one shard?

Tags: apache, tomcat, solr

I am using Solr 4.10.3 and have 8 shards.
Each shard has 1 leader and 1 replica, so a total of 16 cores.
Every core is running on a separate VM.

One of my shard's cores are down. All of them.
How do I recover from this?
Can I add a shard-leader by some command?

I do not want to loose data.

Comment: just to know, are you also using the zookeeper? and how many machines you are using for those 16 shards?

Comment: Hi Aman, Thanks for the reply. I am using zookeeper cluster. There are 9 VMs of medium size with 2 CPU cores each in the zookeeper cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Atleast one replica of each shard should be available.

Lets say shard1 is in node2(leader) and node3(replica).

1. if node2 is down, node3 becomes leader(zookeeper takes care of this). still you can access all docs in that shard.
2. if both node2 and node3 are down, that means access to shard1 is not possible.

check why your core is down in logs.

You cannot add a shard-leader by some command. 
Zookeeper keeps track of which nodes are active and which are not. shard leader is elected by Zookeeper.

Answer (score 0):

As Vinod mentioned, if any of the replica is available you are good to go but if it is not then you have to restart the nodes then zookeeper will read the cluster state and will act accordingly.

I will suggest you to always keep the replica on another node si that if any node got down still solr can process the query.